# how i can create pages dynamically on users any action?

Tags: 7

I want a page creation(dynamically), if user uplooads a design(image) which is (or its info) goes to database. The page name should be on the name of design. How can i do this?

**Update:**
Designs(dress designs[images] ) are submitted by the users through an application which resides on the root of drupal. Not a module of drupal. As the designs are submitted, they goes to a folder at root and relative info goes to drupal database. As i am using drupal bootstrap to get user info and a little more.
So i need a module which listens the request from application(may listen from database updation) and make page of that design with unique path.
Please guide me how to handel this situation

any hint/help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how one can do so.
First make a content type (also can use *Basic Page* type).
Then the below code will make pages(nodes of the content type) dynamically.

```
<?php
// Construct the new node object.
$node = new stdClass();

// Your script will probably pull this information from a database.
$node->title = "My imported node";
$node->body = "The body of my imported node.\n\nAdditional Information";
$node->type = 'mynewpage';   // Your specified content type
$node->created = time();
$node->changed = $node->created;
$node->status = 1;
$node->promote = 1;
$node->sticky = 0;
$node->format = 1;       // Filtered HTML
$node->uid = 1;          // UID of content owner
$node->language = 'en';
// If known, the taxonomy TID values can be added as an array.
$node->taxonomy = array(2,3,1,);

node_save($node);
?>
```

if you need to create nodes at root of Drupal directory you also need to include these lines in start of the code

```
// Bootstrap Drupal
require 'includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```